# Python Division Rounding

Tags: python, division

In Python, is there a good way to divide 1 over 0.99 immediately resulting in 1.01?

In other words, I am dividing a lot (and by a lot I mean millions) of doubles that are rounded to the second place after the decimal. If I divide 1 over 0.99 in Python I get 1.0101010101010102. All I need is the 1.01 portion of this number.

I am aware of the fact that I can round the result, but this is super slow in the context of my application. Is there a faster way to divide two numbers and get a result that is rounded already?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want the actual *result* to be a float with a value of exactly 1.01 (which is impossible), or do you just want to *display* a decimal number with two digits?

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in [**`decimal`**](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module for fixed-point math.